# How to divide the data to analyze [Histograms in R]

Tags: data-visualization, histogram

I am working on the data of a contest, of 85 days duration, where all the participants could choose to participate or not every day.
The distribution seen through a histogram is:

[Histogram with the 14423 participants, with breaks = 85 corresponding to days in which there was at least one participation]

[image]

Analyzing this histogram with:

```
total.data <- hist(temp.df$Freq, breaks = 85)
total.data$breaks
total.data$counts
```

The results are:

```
  [1] 11627 696 399 246 183 133 108 92 70  50  58 61 44 39 32 30 40   19 18
  [20]    13    17    12    12    20    15    17    16    15    11     7    13    10    12    10    12     9    12     7
  [39]     9     9    10     5     6     5     6     9     3     7     7     3     6     5     3     7     7     4     1
  [58]     1     3     7     2     4     5     5     7     5     4     6     2     5     4     7     5     0     7     4
  [77]     5     7     6     9     6     3    10     6
```

Some comments about this histogram:
- There are 11627 people with one day of participation
- There are 696 with 2 days
- There are 399 with 3 days...

If a choose to cut the first 10 days, I can obtain a clearer image about what happened during the contest:

[image]

The purpose of this research is to analyze the behavior of users based on their participation and commitment.
I am wondering the best way to divide the participants, in two or n-parts according days/participation (two big histograms); between those who have participated occasionally (1 day is very casual, 2 o 5 o 10 too?) and those who have participated more frequently in the contest.

My question is: 
1. What is the appropriate criterion to make the cut between the extremely high numbers and the rest of the series?

2. At this time, making the cut when you get to 10 is something totally intuitive (and arbitrary), but it could be in 5 or 11.

I really value any concept or idea that you can suggest about which is the best criterion to make the cut.

My idea so far is to present the general histogram, and then present two histograms, a first histogram for the first 10 days with break = 1, and a second histogram with all the participants that participated more than 10 days, with break = 10.

Attached the link to the dataset with user and participation in the case that someone considers to perform some minimum proof of concept.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tsmjb72pje5emmn/AACkXrnG9vjRWzabwCyMGsyBa?dl=0

Comment: By editing your post, could you explain the purpose of your analysis?  Only that kind of information can help you determine whether and how to focus on the right tail of this distribution.  Otherwise we have no basis to determine how any procedure might be "best."

Comment: Good point and good question! I will edit my post including that information.